# como retorno un valor de una función con addEventListener?

Tags: javascript, funciones, dom

Estoy practicando lo aprendido en `javascript` y me decidí por hacer una lista de tareas donde puedes añadir tareas principales que luego tendrán mini tareas.

Por ejemplo, una tarea principal seria "organizar fiesta de cumpleaños" y las mini-tareas de ella serian comprar pastel,invitar personas, comprar bebidas,comprar globos,etc.

Bien, ya esta casi todo listo, pero el problema está en que yo quiero mostrar las tareas principales en forma de botones, para que cuando quieras pasar de una tarea principal a otra solo debas pisar el botón correspondiente.

Para ello necesito saber el indice del elemento del botón, ésto lo he logrado con un `addEventListener` que hace una función que me detecta el indice.

Hasta aquí todo bien, pero no se porque no me quiere retornar el valor del indice para utilizarlo en otra función. Básicamente es eso, poder retornar el indice para poder usarlo en un `array` luego.

Dejo el código `html` y `js`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>app.me</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" 
    href="css/app.css" /> -->
</head>

<body>
    <div class="contenedorPrincipal">
        <div class="listasPrincipales">
            <input type="text" id="nuevaLista" placeholder="crea tu nueva lista de 
    tareas">

            <!--en este div se guardan los botones que se crean a partir de las 
    tareas principales que se escriben en el input anterior-->
            <div id="contenedorListas"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="abuelo">
            <input type="text" id="input" placeholder="añade la tarea especifica">
            <ul id="listContainer"></ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="ecmas6/appme.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

ok ahora el js

```
let nuevaLista = document.getElementById('nuevaLista');
const inputText = document.getElementById('input')
const listContainer = document.getElementById('listContainer')
let contenedorListasPrincipales = 
document.getElementById('contenedorListas')

//hacer clase donde se crean todas las tareas básicas
//con metodos para saber si se completo o no la tarea

class Tarea{
constructor(name){
    this.name = name;
    this.isComplete = false;
}
completar(){
    this.isComplete = !this.isComplete;
}
}

class ListaDeTareas{
constructor(nameTasksList){
    this.nameTasksList = nameTasksList;
    this.tasksArreglo = [];
}
addTask(tareaToAdd,elemento){
    this.tasksArreglo.push(tareaToAdd);
    this.renderTask(elemento);
}
removeTask(indice,elemento){
    this.tasksArreglo.splice(indice,1)
    this.renderTask(elemento)
}
renderTask(elemento){
    let tareas = this.tasksArreglo.map(task => 
        `
        <li class="tarea ${task.isComplete ? 'complete':''}"> 
        <input type="checkbox" 
        class="tarea__complete-button"
        ${task.isComplete ? 'checked':''}
        >

    <span class="tarea__name">${task.name}</span>
    <a href="#" class="tarea__remove-button">X</a>
    </li>

        `
    );
    elemento.innerHTML = tareas.reduce((a,b) => a+b,'');
}
}

//crear nueva lista
let arrList = [];  //arreglo donde se meten todas las nuevas tareas 
principales

function newList(event) {
if(event.key === "Enter"){
    //añadir tareas principales al array vacio
    arrList.push(new ListaDeTareas(this.value));
    this.value = "";
    //dibujar listas de tareas principales
    let ordenar = arrList.map(listTask => 
        `
        <div>
        <button style="cursor:pointer">
        ${listTask.nameTasksList}
        </button>
        </div>
        <br>
        `

    );
    contenedorListasPrincipales.innerHTML = ordenar.reduce((a,b)=> 
a+b,'');
}
}
//evento para crear nueva lista principal y mostrarla en forma de 
botones
nuevaLista.addEventListener('keyup',newList);

//obtener indice de boton pulsado
function getIndexButton(e) {
let buttonItem = e.target.parentElement;
let buttonsItems = 
[...contenedorListasPrincipales.querySelectorAll('div')];
let indexPrincipal = buttonsItems.indexOf(buttonItem);
console.log(indexPrincipal);

//*=*=*=*=*=*=*=*=*=*=*=*= he aqui el gran problema amigos
//=*=*=*=*=*=*=*=*=*=*=*=*=
return indexPrincipal;
//quiero usar por fuera esta variable pero no puedo
//no se si sera porque estoy utilizando un parametro "e" en la
//funcion getIndexButton, pero es que es necesario porque es una
//funcion de addEventListener asi que cuando la llamo por fuera no se
//como hacerle para ponerle ese parametro
// les indicaré mas abajo donde la quiero usar exactamente... 
}

//evento click en el contenedor de los botones para saber indice del
//boton
contenedorListasPrincipales.addEventListener('click',getIndexButton)


function addDOMTask(evento){

if(evento.key === "Enter"){
    let task = new Tarea(this.value);
//*=*=*=*=*=*=*=*=*=*=*=*=*=*=AQUÍ es una parte donde quiero usar ése
//índice en el array arrList[indice]
//de esa manera puedo agregar tareas pequeñas a su respectiva tarea 
//Principal, ya probé con let i = getIndexButton();
//pero no sirve por culpa de que no tengo parametro para meterle a 
//getIndexButton(parametro??) queria hacer arrList[i].addTask(etc...)
//pero no sirvió       
    arrList[0].addTask(task,listContainer);
    this.value = '';

}
}
//evento para añadir tareas a las tareas principales
inputText.addEventListener("keyup",addDOMTask);


function getTaskIndex(p){
let taskItem = p.target.parentElement;
let tasksItems = [...listContainer.querySelectorAll('li')];
return tasksItems.indexOf(taskItem);
}

function removeDOMTask(evento){
if(evento.target.tagName === 'A'){
//*=*=*=*=*=*=*=*=*=*=*=*=*=*=*=*=*= he aqui la misma historia
//*=*=*=*= que necesito el valor del indice clickado
arrList[0].removeTask(getTaskIndex(evento),listContainer);
}
}

//evento para remover
listContainer.addEventListener('click',removeDOMTask);

function completeDOMTask(evento){
if(evento.target.tagName === 'INPUT'){
//*=*=*=*=*=*=*=*=*=*=*=*=*=*=*=*=*=*=*=*=*=*=*=
//aqui igual
arrList[0].tasksArreglo[getTaskIndex(evento)].completar();

    //para añadir clase al input seleccionado y mejorar visualmente
evento.target.parentElement.classList.toggle('complete')    
}
}
//evento para completar
listContainer.addEventListener('click',completeDOMTask);
```

Bueno, pues eso, necesito retornar ese valor del indice de alguna manera,
que en realidad ya lo tengo pero no lo puedo utilizar.

Espero me hayan entendido y si así no se puede pues ¿de alguna otra manera se podrían obtener los indices de los botones para ir cambiando entre tareas principales?

Comment: solo para aclarar un poquito. pongo arrList[0] con indice cero para que al menos agregue mini-tareas a la primera tarea principal. ese indice es el que quiero cambiar a gusto. ó a gusto del usuario mejor dicho

Comment: No entiendo bien tu pregunta, ¿a qué te refieres con *obtener el índice  del botón pulsado*, a un índice en un array, a su id, a un valor que hay en el botón? En la función `function getIndexButton(e) {` deberías tener una referencia del elemento pulsado y mediante `this` podrías obtener cualquier propiedad o atributo de ese elemento. Por ejemplo: `this.id;  this.name; this.class` y así cualquier propiedad del botón que haya sido pulsado.

Comment: @A.Cedano hola, lo que quiero usar en realidad es el indice del div, si te fijas en `function newList(event)` se crea un `<div>` que dentro tiene un `<button>` cada uno de estos divs con botones dentro se van creando a medida que escribes una nueva lista de tareas y pulsas enter.

Comment: @A.Cedano y ese indice me servirá para luego utilizarlo en la función `addDOMTask()` para luego poder agregar tareas a las Tareas Principales con `addTask()` de la siguiente manera `arrList[indiceQnecesito].addTask(task,listContainer)`  EN RESUMEN: el objetivo principal de obtener ese indice es porque dentro de `arrList[]` tengo listas de tareas "como por ej: quehaceres del hogar, actividades de fin de semana,etc"  y dandole a esos botones puedo ir cambiando de listas para agregar o quitar mas tareas. Me he hecho entender?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Simple mente no se puede, así no funciona la vida XD……**

Necesitas almacenar el valor que quieres retornar en alguna variable o propiedad de clase fuera del callback para que una vez ejecutado el evento puedas acceder a su valor.
Esa función que le pasas al addEventListener es un callback  es decir, la referencia de na función almacenada en una variable.

Ejemplo:

```
let variable = '';

function eventHandler(event) {
  //hacer algo ...
  console.log(event.target);
  variable = 'foo';
}

listContainer.addEventListener('click', eventHandler);
```

Comment: Vaya!! si me sirvio, muchas gracias! ,ahora si puedo cambiar entre tareas principales al darle a los botones. Bueno XD  al parecer mi problema era algo básico sobre los addEventListener ya que pensaba que se podia hacer como cualuier otra funcion que retorna un valor.pero como aqui debe utilizarse un parametro a juro por ser un evento la mejor opcion es una variable por fuera. MUCHISIMAS GRACIAS por aclararme esa duda. Saludos